# Turn a circuit on and off when a capacitor reaches a certain voltage

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, supercapacitor

I have a circuit that takes an input voltage of 0.5-1.5 volts and uses it to charge a supercapacitor up to around 4 volts. However, I only need the capacitor to be charged up to 3 volts. What is the simplest way with commonly available discrete components (including resistors, capacitors, NPN and PNP transistors, power transistors/power MOSFETs, 2N6027 PUTs, and various diodes) to turn off power to the charging circuit when the capacitor's voltage goes over 3 volts and turn it on when the voltage drops below around 2.8 volts?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpfmuB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: 3V Zener diode?

Comment: 555 used as a schmitt trigger?

Comment: That could work, but a 555 timer will not work at that voltage.

Comment: Why dont you inhibit the cap charger because this can be done at low current.

Comment: B-but the power of cmos...

Comment: There are many circuit topologies that could be used to cut off the charge but most of those will require a supply voltage higher than what you have available as the input voltage rail _(0.5V is too low to activate semiconductor junctions)_. So this leads to a question...does the capacitor charger circuit supply enough current at 2.8V and above at a steady voltage that it can be used for operating the cut off circuit?

Comment: The capacitor charger can supply at least 30mA continuous current at whatever voltage the supercapacitor is charged to when it is running. I could possibly also redesign it to charge a second smaller capacitor to a higher voltage if that would help.

Comment: What prevents you from changing the charger circuit to only provide up to 3Volts?  It might be easier to modify it than to add some external circuit.

Comment: It still needs to shut off when the capacitor becomes charged.

Answer (score 2):

I would perhaps use a relay, with discrete components you won't necessarily get good accuracy. If you don't want a huge relay hanging around, I would use a comparator with voltage reference. I'd say using discretes in this case won't really cut it, unless you aren't looking for accuracy. Another option is to build the comparators out of transistors, but that sounds pretty painful.

Comment: Would I be able to use 2N6027 programmable unijunction transistors for anything? I have at least 25 of them lying around not being used for anything.

Comment: Possibly. I personally have never used those.